# Javascript distinguish a function in an object

Tags: javascript, object, typeof

Having an object like this:

```
var a = {

  b: "string",
  c: function(){
    return "i return a string"; 
  }    
}
```

Doing

```
for (var key in a) {
    console.log(typeof key);
};
```

Returns "string", "string" since b is a string and c returns a string.

Is there afunction that returns c -> function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Returns "string", "string" since b is a string and c returns a string.

**No**. The reason it returns `string`, is that the attribute name `b` and the attribute name `c` are both strings; you're iterating over the keys of the object, not their values right now.

You could introduce attribute `d`, which was a function which returned a number or boolean, and you'd still get `string`.

Instead, enumerate over the values themselves;

```
for (var x in a) {
    console.log(typeof a[x] );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the type of the property instead of its key, should use the value together with the `typeof` operator.

```
for (var key in a) {
    console.log(typeof a[key] );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you will always get **strings** by **iterating trough the keys** of your object since they are represented as such.

But if you for example do  `console.log(typeof a[key]);` Then you will get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
for (var key in a) {
    console.log(typeof a[key]);
};​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NEsLQ/)

```
console.log(typeof key); // gives you the key - "c"
console.log(typeof a[key]); // gives you the value of the "c" key - function.
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain this little bit, so it's easy to understand to anyone. (its my first post here anyway.)

Try the following code, it says its a **function**.

```
console.log(typeof(a.c))
```

But what you have written is reading the property names. Try the following code to understand what's wrong with your code.

```
for (var key in a) {
    console.log(key);
};
```

So basically what you are getting is correct. Because all property names are string.
Remember JSON objects have several restrictions, such as case sensitive, full path needed to traverse to properties etc..

Change your code as follows to get the typeof your properties,

Solution 1:

```
console.log(typeof(a[key]));
```

Solution 2:

```
console.log(typeof(eval('a.'+ key)));
```

Comment: i think it's better to avoid eval and instead use a[key], anyay thanks!